# PHP laravel class not found. How can I use namespaces to fix this?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm using the Laravel framework and have a directory of the following structure:

```
models 
  Statistic.php

presenters
  StatisticPresenter.php
```

In my `models/Statistic` class, I'm trying to access a `present` method which calls a protected property which then references my presenter:

```
protected $presenter = 'presenters\StatisticPresenter';

public function present() {
    return new $this->presenter($this); 
}
```

Yet, this returns the error: `Class 'presenters\StatisticPresenter' not found`. I realize this is a namespacing error of some sort, and I've tried watching a few videos on how it works, but I simply can't wrap my head around it. I have already added my presenter folder to my `composer.json` file. For example, adding this to the top of my `Statistic` model does not work:

```
use presenters\StatisticPresenter;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you haven't already, run `composer dump-autoload`. You can also try adding a backslash in at the beginning: `'\presenters\StatisticPresenter'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the followings;

- Mark your namespace in StatisticPresenter.php ? (at the top of file "namespace presenters;")
- Add PSR-4 class map to your composer

`{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "presenters\\": "app/presenters/"
        }
    }
}`

- run "composer dump-autoload" once and you wont need to run this command again for the **"presenters"** namespace if you add new classes into **"app/presenters/ folder"**
- Test your class with "use presenters/StatisticPresenter;"
- If you can access your class you dont need to change your code your present() function will be valid